# How create border in stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage

I need advice, please. I'm working on one project - a simple game. It will be something like "Space Invaders". I just needed to cater to the ship could not leave the area (Stage). Function, is called "RMimoXY" does not work. Could someone please check out what I'm missing in the program?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.display.Stage;

var let: Boolean = false;
var pozadi: Stage;
var vx:Number = 0;
var vy:Number = 0;

function mezernik(){
    var mySound: Sound = new laserFire(); 
    mySound.play();
    RMimoXY();
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, klavesnice);

function klavesnice(e: KeyboardEvent){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.LEFT: lod.x += -5; break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT: lod.x += 5; break;
        case Keyboard.UP: lod.y += -5; break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN: lod.y += 5; break;
        case Keyboard.SPACE: mezernik(); break;
    }
}

function RMimoXY(){
    if (lod.x > stage.stageWidth ){ 
        lod.x =  0 - lod.width; 
    } 
    else if (lod.x < 0 - lod.width ){ 
        lod.x = stage.stageWidth; 
    } 
    if (lod.y > stage.stageHeight ){ 
        lod.y = 0 - lod.height; 
    } 
    else if (lod.y < 0 - lod.height ){ 
        lod.y = stage.stageHeight; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to run this method on every frame , like: `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, RMimoXY);` , and change its definition like `function RMimoXY(e:Event):void`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but don't function it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you're only calling `RMimoXY` in your constructor. You should call it every time the ship is moved. So adding it to the end of your keyhandler should work:

```
function klavesnice(e: KeyboardEvent){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.LEFT: lod.x += -5; break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT: lod.x += 5; break;
        case Keyboard.UP: lod.y += -5; break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN: lod.y += 5; break;
        case Keyboard.SPACE: mezernik(); break;
    }
    RMimoXY();
}
```